# Adding classes to micropython module

Tags: micropython

In reference to [adding module in micropython](http://micropython-dev-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding-module.html#classes), I was trying to create a class which has a local method. In the documentation it is given how to add local methods and that the first argument should be of `mp_obj_t` type which is the data struct itself. However, I was asking how can I pass extra parameters like other methods? I tried using `mp_obj_t * args` as second argument but `STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_1` gives error. I tried the same with `STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_VAR` but it does not support passing `mp_obt_t` as first argument as `STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_VAR` needs an `int`. I am quite new, so I was asking how to add methods to classes which can accept arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You need `MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_2`, since you have 2 arguments.
Something like

```
STATIC mp_obj_t my_class_func(mp_obj_t self, mp_obj_t arg) {
  if (MP_OBJ_IS_SMALL_INT(lhs)) {
    const mp_int_t lhs_val = MP_OBJ_SMALL_INT_VALUE(arg);
    //...
  } else {
    //oops, not an int
  }
  return mp_const_none;
}
MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_2(my_class_func_obj, my_class_func);
```

The best source of samples like this is the source code btw.

Answer (score 1):

To eleaborate on @stijn answer ~ when creating a class, all the `MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_XXXXXX` defines work the exact same as they would if you weren't creating a class. The only difference is the first argument of ACTUAL arguments will always refer to `self`

Here's an example:

```cpp
mp_obj_t Class_method(mp_uint_t n_args, const mp_obj_t *args) { ... }
```

That is the standard candidate for:

```c
MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_VAR_BETWEEN(Class_method_obj, 1, 3, Class_method);
```

However, in this case `args[0]` will be `self`.

Let's have another example.

```cpp
mp_obj_t Class_method(mp_uint_t n_args, const mp_obj_t *args, mp_map_t *kw_args) { ... }
```

That's a prime candidate for this define

```cpp
MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_KW(Class_method_obj, 2, Class_method);
```

The only difference in this case is that the first index of `allowed_args` needs to automatically be handled as `self`. Nothing about how you do these things changes, except now the first ACTUAL argument (ie not including `n_args` or any other "helper" argument) needs to automatically be considered as `self`. That being said, you will NEVER use `MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_0` with a class method. '_0' means "zero arguments" and a class method will never have zero arguments because it will ALWAYS at least have `self`. This also means that you have to add one to however many expected arguments you have on the python end. If your python version accepts 3 arguments ~

```
(red, green, blue)
```

then your C_MODULE define has to start at 4 because it's going to get

```
(self, red, green, blue)
```